# Is there any shortcut for removing text style in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I am new to the LaTex and TeXstudio, so I am not completely familiar with all the options and features.

Currently I use Cmd+B or Cmd+I for emphasizing/italicizing. **But is there also a shortcut for removing these styles?** 
As far as I understand, a LaTeX editor doesn't work like Word that repeating the action disables it.

I know I can just undo, but when after many changes I come back to the styled text, the only way to remove it seems to manually delete the command.

Comment: You are right when you said "the only way to remove seems to manually delete the commands", but you can in fact disable emboldening (or whichever formatting command eg. underlining, italicizing) at the beginning of the document, so those commands (across the document) won't have any effect on the text. You don't even need to see where you have put them. This is called a 'global change' in TeX (Also you can't do this in word.)

Comment: this feature is not supported in TeXstudio. you might want to put in a feature request with the DEVs of TXS.

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, but I normally want to remove only 1 or 2 instances. Is there any way to customize these formatting commands and switching them on/off? (something like classes in css)